# Композиция vs. наследование: может ли иметь человек атрибут «дата добавления записи в БД» наряду с атрибутом «имя»?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, инспекция-кода, наследование

Проектирую доменную область сервиса для тестирования. В различных тестированиях будут принимать участие различные категории участников: ученик школы, учитель школы и бывший ученик школы, который является бывшим учеником данной школы. Необходимо отметить, что бывший ученик школы при тестировании привязывается в целом к школе, класса у него нет (он ведь уже отучился).

В сети часто можно встреть утверждение, что необходимо по возможности использовать композицию нежели наследование. Но также есть другое утверждение, с которым я больше согласен и это: необходимо просто понять какая из двух связей существует `is` *(наследование)* или `has` *(композиция/агрегация)*.

---

Вот мои классы:

```
/// <summary>
/// При тестировании бывших учеников школы, используются объекты данного класса
/// </summary>
public class SchoolParticip
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Ходил ли участник в садик до поступления в школу?
    /// </summary>
    public bool WentKindergarten { get; set; }
    public School School { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string DataSourceName { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Ученик школы
/// </summary>
public class ClassParticip : SchoolParticip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс в школе
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>1А | 3Б и т.п.</example>
    /// <remarks>Class - это отдельный класс</remarks>
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Учитель школы
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Объекты данного класса используются, когда проходит какое-то тестирование учителей,
/// которые также закреплены за определенными школами.
/// </remarks>
public class TeachParticip : SchoolParticip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Стаж работы
    /// </summary>
    public int Experience { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Категория
    /// </summary>        
    /// <remarks>
    /// Класс Category описывает категории (первая категория, высшая категория и т.д.).
    /// </remarks>
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

---

### ВОПРОС

Вопрос в целом звучит так:

**1. Правильно ли я сделал, в первую очередь с концептуальной точки зрение, что выбрал тут наследование, а не композицию?**

А подвопрос такой:

1.1) Эти сущности будут проецироваться на таблицу реляционной базы данных и мне необходимы поля `AddedDate` — время добавления записи и `DataSourceName` — наименование источника данных (при добавлении через ЛК это будет название логина). Но с концептуальной точки зрения разве правильно звучит утверждение "Я участник тестирования и у меня есть свойство «ВремяДобавленияМеняВбазуДанных»"? Разве можно подобные свойства ставить на ряду с такими как Фамилия и Имя. Быть может тут какой-то паттерн необходим? Каких знаний в проектировании мне не хватает?

Comment: "Я участник тестирования и у меня есть свойство «ДатаВыдачиПаспорта»", по вашему звучит лучше?

Comment: А почему у вас не People (Name, LastName и был ли в садике до школы) и набор записей когда в каких классах был? (С датами начала-конца), номером и буквой класса?

Comment: @Mirdin не совсем. Тогда было бы: у меня есть паспорт (композиция) у которого есть свойство ДатаВыдачи.

Comment: @AK Был такой абстрактный класс `People`  Собственно его я и превратил в `SchoolParticp`.

Comment: Для учителя интересно получается `WentKindergarten`  :)

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин думаете не стоит столь сильно привязываться к реальности?

Comment: Хоть я и не это имел ввиду, но мысль верная.

Comment: Для принятия решения проще всего будет сразу же и привести код с композицией, и думаю сразу станет ясно что лучше.

Comment: А по поводу `AddedDate` и `DataSourceName` нет никаких мыслей?

Comment: `AddedDate` вполне нормальное решение, всё-таки вы не человека храните в базе данных, а запись...

Comment: Я разные по природе свойства просто парой пустых строчек отделяю, или можно комментарием.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин честно говоря не совсем понял что Вы имели ввиду. Или речь идёт о разделении свойства чем-то типа #region ... #endregion ?

Comment: да, это и имел ввиду, но я бы так не делал, повторяю что вы храните не людей в таблице, а записи, а для записи вполне нормально хранить время добавления

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Если говорить о сигнальных английских глаголах связанных с отношениями между классами, то `Composition` - это `has a ...`, а вот `Aggregation` - это `part of ...`.

2) Надо отдавать себе отчет в том, что совет отдавать предпочтение композиции перед наследованием вполне себе оправдан из-за того, что зачастую программист начинает построение иерархической системы из классов, которая порой ничем не оправдана кроме как желанием поменьше написать повторяющихся названий свойств, например "... О! `Id` - создам-ка я класс `Entity`..." и так далее. В результате такого подхода возникает иерархическая система из классов, которая в принципе может быть не нужна в приложении, а может даже и очень сильно мешать в дальнейшем. К наследованию лучше прибегать в случае если вы начинаете проектирование с абстракций, т.е. начинаете программировать с интерфейсов и абстрактных классов, хотя в случае интерфейсов наследование называется реализацией, но вы меня понимаете...

3) Конкретно в вашем случае, на мой скромный взгляд, у вас есть сущности: `Человек`, `Опыт` и связанная с ним `ТипОпыта` - это буквально словарные названия (Ученик, Учитель и т.д.), которые хранятся в отдельной таблице БД. Сущность `Опыт` должна иметь соотв. свойства (ДатаНачала, ДатаОкончания, ТипОпыта, Стаж, ну и проч. что надо), таким образом по таблице `Опыт` в БД можно отследить весь учебный и трудовой путь нужного человека.

А вот это ваше наследование никуда не годится.

4) "...AddedDate — время добавления записи и DataSourceName — наименование источника данных..." такие вещи выносят в отдельные таблицы в БД с отношением "один-к-одному". Т.е. есть таблица "Человек" а к ней "прицепом" отдельная таблица "ЧеловекСекретное", в которой будут хранится логин, пароль и проч. служебная инфа.